# setInterval in MovieClip.prototype

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

how can i use setInterval in movieClip.prototype?
this code increase num value just one time...

```
   MovieClip.prototype.testFunc = function(num) {
        var num = isNaN(num) ? 0 : num;
        trace(num);
        clearInterval(this.slideDelay);
        num++;
        this.slideDelay = setInterval(this.testFunc, 4000,num);
    };
    var testMc = _root.createEmptyMovieClip("testMc", 1);
    testMc.testFunc(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a confusing part of ActionScript/JavaScript: the value of the "this" keyword can be different depending on the context in which the function was called. When your testFunc is called the second time (by setInterval), the "this" value is undefined. That makes clearInterval fail, as well as your subsequent calls to setInterval.

Use this as your setInterval call to get the effect you want:

```
this.slideDelay = setInterval(this, "testFunc", 4000, num);
```